# How does Laravel Email Verification (technically) work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using the standard laravel registration system (`php artisan make:auth`) and i'm currently wondering how the verification of the mail in laravel works. I don't see any token or something else in the database that could be compared to the one from the "registration-complete" mail of laravel (after sign-up).
So how does Laravel acutally make sure that the token is correct?

I already looked in the RegistraterController and think it must have to do something with the `User::create()` method that is called in the `create` method of the Controller. But, unfortunateley, i even can not find this method...
(My Laravel is running on version 5.8.7)

Comment: You can look at the documentation perhaps, as the best place to find such answers:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/verification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel uses so-called signed routes for this purpose that hash the URL with a secret key, so there is no need to store tokens. See[`Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::signedRoute`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L331)

This function is called via [`Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php#L60) from [`Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.php#L36) trait used in [`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php#L19) model.

On user request the hash is then validated by [`Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::hasValidSignature`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L368)

Comment: Are all such URLs signed with the same key? If so, how can one change this key? If not, where are the hashes stored for comparison when the user clicks?
I was hoping to use the same or similar mechanism for unsubscribing users

Comment: Yes, all are signed with the same key, it uses config value `app.key`.
see: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/43bea00fd27c76c01fd009e46725a54885f4d2a5/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php#L78